# fsockopen(): unable to connect to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465 (Connection timed out)

Tags: php, codeigniter, openssl, gmail, debian

```
$config['protocol']='smtp';
$config['smtp_host']='ssl://smtp.gmail.com'; //(SMTP server)
$config['smtp_port']='465'; //(SMTP port)
$config['smtp_timeout']='60';
$config['smtp_user']='xxxxxxx@gmail.com';
$config['smtp_pass']='xxxxxx';//secure password gmail
$config['mailtype'] = 'html';
$config['charset'] = 'utf-8';
$config['newline'] = "\r\n";
```

I can't sending email notification from my web. i check my log there is error **fsockopen(): unable to connect to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465 (Connection timed out)**

I don't think that there is anything wrong with my email.php config. I have checked that my **phpinfo()** ssl is enabled. I try to using **tls** but it still doesn't work.

Before this i have install ssl certificate on my web server but there is no problem. My web server (Debian) is running well with valid certificate.

How should I go about debugging and solving this?